# How to make Proximity Alerts work even when the mobile screen is Locked?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, proximity

I've created application to send `Proximity Alert` via SMS. SMS delivering fine. But when my phone scree is locked Proximity Alert failed to fire alert. I don't want my phone screen awake all times and i still want my app to alert even the screen is locked or sleep. Any Solutions to it.
This is my code for adding `Proximity Alert` in Main Activity's `onCreate()`

```
try{
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select rowid _id,*from latLngTable", null);
        go=cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (cursor.isAfterLast()!=true){
                String strLat = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
                String strLng = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"));
                String mobileNo=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone_NO"));

                double dLat = Double.parseDouble(strLat);
                double dLng = Double.parseDouble(strLng);
                float radius = 2000;

                LocationManager locationManager2 = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationManager2.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                String proximitys = "com.realtech.latlngrecorder" + n;
                Intent i = new Intent(proximitys);
                i.putExtra("phone", mobileNo);
                sendBroadcast(i);

                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, n, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                locationManager2.addProximityAlert(dLat, dLng, radius, -1, pi);
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(proximitys);
                registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
                Log.w("Alert Added", "Alert Added to All Locations");
                Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Proximity Alert Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                n++;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainPage.this,"Failed to add Proximity Alert",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My `BroadcastReceiver` for proximity alert was

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    smsNo=intent.getStringExtra("phone");

    String proximityKey= LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    Boolean entering=intent.getBooleanExtra(proximityKey,false);
    if (entering){
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();
            String[] numbers=smsNo.split(",");
            for (String number:numbers) {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, "School Van will reach your place in 2 mins.\n\u0bb8\u0bcd\u0b95\u0bc2\u0bb2\u0bcd \u0bb5\u0bc7\u0ba9\u0bcd \u0bb5\u0bb0\u0baa\u0bcd\u0baa\u0bcb\u0b95\u0bbf\u0bb1\u0ba4\u0bc1.", null, null);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
        Toast.makeText(context,"exiting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

And another thing if i restart the app the event fires again.
Please help me to run my app always in background even if the user closes it. Thank you.